# How do you rewrite http to https for an addon domain in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a cPanel hosting account at Godaddy with an SSL for an addon domain. I need to rewrite http to https. The problem is that all methods of rewrite are loading from the webroot, not the folder containing the index or even the htaccess that has the rewrite rule. I know there are topics on this already on this forum but I have tried those suggested solution, that's how I have what you see in the code quote, and they did not work. Please do not arbitrarily close this thread.

```
webroot (loading this content / not desired)
      |
       target_directory (htaccess & SSL in question)
```

The following is the complete htaccess at the time of this post

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://emeraldcoast\.rocks/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/$ index.php?page=$1

<filesMatch ".(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A7200
Header append Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch ".(xml|txt|html|php)$">
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</filesMatch>
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a control panel especially cpanel takes control of the server and configures things a lot differently than a standard setup. Anyway, you might need add a rewritebase to your addon domain. Inside .htaccess for the addon domain change the rewritebase to your addon folder.

```
RewriteBase /target_directory
```